# network slow on port 80 only

Tags: networking, unix, mac, wifi

i'm trying to diagnose why our company's wifi network is running really slow.  the network is wpa2 encrypted, and there hasn't been any other traffic accessing our network other than the 5 computers in our office. i've tried using connections on other ports (ftp,ssh,bitorrent), all of which run fine.  however, when browsing the web (port 80), everything is extremely slow (2kb connection speeds).  any ideas on unix (or gui) tools i could use to further diagnose this issue, or immediate thoughts on what the issue might be? we're all on macs in the office.

cheers

Comment: How are you checking "port 80"? With something like wget, or are you relying on the browser?

Comment: i tried downloading an arbitrary file with curl.

Comment: i'm also running slurm as well

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any internal servers with anything running on 80? If you do, can you see if the speed decrease exists before you hit your router?

Do you have any kind of traffic shaper (I doubt it considering the size of the office, but it doesn't hurt to ask)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a consumer-type router for your network? Maybe it's checking port 80 packets for malware.

Comment: Some home routers do basic filtering of traffic, I'd say that isn't a bad theory.

How do SSL connections run?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using at the moment?

Run a speedtest (google speedtest) and see what it says. Alternatively wget/curl a large file and see what result you get.

What other traffic is running? Other users running bittorrent can really clog a network. Try using 1 PC with the others off.

How good is your connection to the base station? kismac will give you some good stats here, but there are plenty of tools.

Then, try a traceroute and see what hops you're going through. I would assume it'll be the access point, then router, then outside world. Something different might point you in the wrong direction.

Of course, there are also the basic fallbacks of rebooting the access point, router, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Diagnosing port 80 traffic, primarily speed should be done directly from the brick (router). If you've got clients connected, there is no way to get an accurate test from a client machine.

Since you have 5 computers I would first try connecting one pc directly to the modem/router provided by ISP. Then determine the speed from there. If this step checks out fine then there is no problem with the line. Hook your wifi router and try the same machine over the wifi. If this doesn't then it's the device. Is this a commercial device? Perhaps there is bandwidth restriction (misconfigured)?

Make sure you are using the correct DNS? If you are using your ISP DNS, re-confirm the addresses with them. They have a tendency of changing them (some ISP). Try manually adding the DNS ip addresses to one of the client machine and see if that works.